# How to fill rows with data from another row with the same reference value?

Tags: r, matrix

After applying an algorithm on a table, the desired results only applied to one of the corresponding rows even if there were several. I would like to fill the blanks with the corresponding values.

I've tried using functions to fill blanks from values to values but this is not what I expect to do. As an example, the REF "80" has nothing to get filled. I've tried adding "if statements" without satisfying results.

Starting table :

```
╔═══╤═════╤═════╤═════╗
║   │ REF │ SC1 │ SC2 ║
╠═══╪═════╪═════╪═════╣
║ 1 │ 42  │     │     ║
╟───┼─────┼─────┼─────╢
║ 2 │ 42  │     │     ║
╟───┼─────┼─────┼─────╢
║ 3 │ 42  │ VU  │ NT  ║
╟───┼─────┼─────┼─────╢
║ 4 │ 80  │     │     ║
╟───┼─────┼─────┼─────╢
║ 5 │ 56  │     │     ║
╟───┼─────┼─────┼─────╢
║ 6 │ 56  │     │     ║
╟───┼─────┼─────┼─────╢
║ 7 │ 56  │ DD  │ NA  ║
╚═══╧═════╧═════╧═════╝
```

Do the table code :

```
table <- matrix(c(42,"","",42,"","",42,"VU","NT",80,"","",56,"","",56,"","",56,"DD","NA"),ncol=3,byrow=TRUE)
colnames(table) <- c("REF","SC1","SC2")
rownames(table) <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
table <- as.table(table)
```

Expected table :

```
╔═══╤═════╤═════╤═════╗
║   │ REF │ SC1 │ SC2 ║
╠═══╪═════╪═════╪═════╣
║ 1 │ 42  │ VU  │ NT  ║
╟───┼─────┼─────┼─────╢
║ 2 │ 42  │ VU  │ NT  ║
╟───┼─────┼─────┼─────╢
║ 3 │ 42  │ VU  │ NT  ║
╟───┼─────┼─────┼─────╢
║ 4 │ 80  │     │     ║
╟───┼─────┼─────┼─────╢
║ 5 │ 56  │ DD  │ NA  ║
╟───┼─────┼─────┼─────╢
║ 6 │ 56  │ DD  │ NA  ║
╟───┼─────┼─────┼─────╢
║ 7 │ 56  │ DD  │ NA  ║
╚═══╧═════╧═════╧═════╝
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In base R keeping your string "NA":

```
table <- matrix(c(42,"","",42,"","",42,"VU","NT",80,"","",56,"","",56,"","",56,"DD","NA"),ncol=3,byrow=TRUE)
colnames(table) <- c("REF","SC1","SC2")
rownames(table) <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)

keys <- table[rowSums(apply(table, 2, nchar) > 0) == 3, ]
merge(data.frame(REF = table[, "REF"]), keys, all = TRUE)

>   REF  SC1  SC2
1  42   VU   NT
2  42   VU   NT
3  42   VU   NT
4  56   DD   NA
5  56   DD   NA
6  56   DD   NA
7  80 <NA> <NA>
```

Comment: It calculates the number of characters in each element of `table`. I keep only rows that have all the 3 columns with values to make a vector of keys in order to merge it with your initial table

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanations @Clemsang.

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr` and a custom made function.

```
library(dplyr)
table <- matrix(c(42,"","",42,"","",42,"VU","NT",80,"","",56,"","",56,"","",56,"DD","NA"),
                ncol=3,
                byrow=TRUE)
colnames(table) <- c("REF","SC1","SC2")
rownames(table) <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
#table <- as.table(table) ## i am not using this command
```

Creating a function that replaces `""` with the closest non `""` value

```
replace_with_last<-function(x, a = !is.na(x)){
  x[which(a)[c(1, 1:sum(a))][cumsum(a)+1]]
}
```

Executing

```
foo <- table %>%
  as_tibble %>%
  group_by(REF) %>%
  mutate(SC1 = replace_with_last(x = SC1, a = SC1 != ""),
         SC2 = replace_with_last(x = SC2, a = SC2 != ""))
```

Which results in

```
  REF   SC1   SC2  
  <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 42    VU    NT   
2 42    VU    NT   
3 42    VU    NT   
4 80    NA    NA   
5 56    DD    NA   
6 56    DD    NA   
7 56    DD    NA
```

Answer (score 0):

a data.table approach..

first convert table to data.table
then join on itself

```
library(data.table)
DT <- setDT( as.data.frame.matrix( table, stringsAsFactors = FALSE ) )
DT[ DT[!SC1 == "",], `:=`( SC1 = i.SC1, SC2 = i.SC2 ), on = "REF"][]

#    REF SC1 SC2
# 1:  42  VU  NT
# 2:  42  VU  NT
# 3:  42  VU  NT
# 4:  80        
# 5:  56  DD  NA
# 6:  56  DD  NA
# 7:  56  DD  NA
```

Comment: It works thank you ! I wasn't aware of this package. The @Clemsang solution is a bit more easier to use because it doesn't need to spell all the columns.